# good web hosting for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting, aws

I am new to Magento, and today I ordered a web hosting plan; but I discovered that their servers does not support Magento CE version.

It took me 2 hours to search for a good web hosting but I couldn't find any one that I am sure is good.

**Edit:** I didn't read the rules (sorry for that), so my question was containing two parts. I will explain the first part, as the second part is not allowed.

I am planing to create a start-up store, and from what I saw the major companies provides three ways of hosting the website: Server (VPS or dedicated), shared hosting and cloud hosting. So for a start up its hard to cover the cost of the server, so what is better shared hosting or cloud? in terms of maintainability, usability and reliability.

My plan was to start with shared hosting, then move to the cloud service either AWS or any Magento partner company. So is the cloud service better than dedicated server, and can the cloud service replace the dedicated server in the future?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping for website hosting.

Comment: I edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using Magento for almost 3 years, and having used a few companies, I would thoroughly recommend Nimbus Hosting:

https://www.nimbushosting.co.uk/

They offer the best value for money currently, but the most important thing is that their service is exceptional. Rapid response time on support and they can handle a lot of your setup processes for you.

VPS sounds like your best bet to start with, and you can then expand to a dedicated server further down the line.

Important to take your location into consideration when choosing your server/hosting company. You'll need a server to be based in the same location as your customers and you are. Hoping this helps?

Answer (score 2):

besides the ones already mentioned, magemojo is also good. It depends on your budget, below $25 go with siteground, hostgator, or similar, $25+ Nexcess, $60+ Magemojo is good.

good place to check also is Magento official hosting partners: http://partners.magento.com/partner_locator/search.aspx?f0=Types+of+Partners&f0v0=Hosting+Partner

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you get a VPS for yourself or a shared server that will let you install varnish. Varnish really helps the speed of a website otherwise Magento could run quite slow on your website.

Comment: could you suggest a company, thats my problem I dont know a good company

Comment: I have seen hostgator work just fine.